# CSS :after content and absolute position for button makes it not clickable

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic framework to develop a mobile app and am testing it using the Ripple emulator. I can't click buttons. I think this problem came along with a Chrome update, but I'm not sure. I have isolated the problem down to the following css in the default ionic.css:

```
  .button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    right: -6px;
    bottom: -6px;
    left: -6px;
    content: ' '; }
```

the problem can be easily produced as follows:

```
<button class="button">hello</button>
```

Please see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNXpaV

It seems this is caused by some interplay of the position and content properties being set. I can fix the problem by removing `content: ' '` or by setting `content: normal` in a second css block (I don't want to modify the ionic.css source)....but why is this happening?

Comment: I can click that button in Firefox. Is it just in Chrome that you have the error?

Comment: The button is still clickable in Firefox (but only on the button) whereas in Chrome, it is 'clickable' anywhere in the body section (probably because of your top/right/bottom/left values).

Comment: It's not clickable for me anywhere in chrome. Try right clicking...nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `:after` content spans the entire page. If you added `background: red` to the CSS, you would what I mean by this.

When an element is `position: absolute`, the `top` `left` `right` and `bottom` coordinates are relative to the nearest parent with a specified `position` attribute. In this case the parent element is `body`.

Pointer events do not go through pseudo-elements by default which is why you cannot click the button through the overlay (I hope this makes intuitive sense).

Try adding `pointer-events: none` to `:after`. You should now be able to click the button even though it is underneath the red block, because `none` tells the browser to ignore pointer events on the `:after` pseudo-element.

```
.button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    right: -6px;
    bottom: -6px;
    left: -6px;
    content: ' ';
    background: red;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

(see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgVZxV)

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Only to demonstrate the fact that the pointer events are captured by the `:after` element, not really as a fix for the problem.

Comment: @Jeff I'm not sure, can you provide more details?

Comment: @Jeff looks like the button is intended to work as a relative (or absolute) positioned element. If this was the case, as Xing points out, the afert pseudoelement would be positioned around the button, and not around the body. So, the most probable origin of the change is that you changed the position property of the button

Comment: Not my change. This is css in ionic framework...and I didn't update to a new version any time recently.